# Natural language logic statement or an abstract statement in a logic puzzle

Tags: logic

Here's an example puzzle from "To Mock a Mockingbird" by Raymond Smullyan

> Suppose I offer to give you one of three prizes-Prize A, Prize B, or Prize C. Prize A is the best of the three, Prize B is middling, and Prize C is the booby prize. You are to make a statement; if the statement is true, then I promise to award you either Prize A or Prize B, but if your statement is false, then you get Prize C-the booby prize.
> Of course it is easy for you to be sure to win either Prize A or Prize B; all you need say is: "Two plus two is four." But suppose you have your heart set on Prize A-what statement could you make which would force me to give you Prize A?

The answer to the puzzle as the author has stated it is: (click to find out the answer)

> "I will not get prize B"

I sent this puzzle to a friend of mine and he came back with an answer:

`A is the best prize OR I get prize A`

Being a computer programmer he though of the problem as if it is being asked by a computer instead of a human. His answer could take anything of the form of `(Something true) OR I get prize A` and we are using inclusive OR.

So here is my question: Although his statement is valid and works to match the requirement of the puzzle it seems off - it makes no sense but nevertheless it is a valid logical statement. What would be the reason that this answer cannot be accepted -  can someone refresh my memory in logic theory. Thanks

Comment: Not following.  $A$ is indeed the best prize so the statement, with the inclusive OR, is true.  Thus, if you are handed $B$, the host is honoring the rules.

Comment: You could give him prize $B$ and still be correct. 
"A is best prize" will remain true, and so will the statement.  So it only prevents you from getting prize $C$. 

You need something that is true when you get A,  (so you can get A) false when you get B (so you can't get B), and true when you get C (so you can't get C).

Comment: @lulu @user3257842 Thanks. We have blindly missed the fact that the statement is true hence it doesn't solve the puzzle. Regardless - the `A is the best prize OR I get prize A` statement is pointless - which logic term can we apply to such a statement ? (as opposed to the statement in the actual answer that totally makes sense)